# How to create wildcard controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

In a default application ASP.NET MVC 3.0 app I have a controller with Index() and Details(string id) methods. These map to /orders/ and orders/details/ORDER_ID_HERE. How do I change the routing so that Details maps to orders/ORDER_ID_HERE, and continue to have Index() serve up a default index page?

Answer (score 2):

If you would add a new route to you route collection like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Detailed", // Route name
    "{contoller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Orders", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

It would work, but you break a lot of things, a url like *[site]/Home/Search* for instance would result in a:

> System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'MvcApplication3.Controllers.OrdersController'.

The reason for this is that */Home/Search* matches the route `{controller}/{id}`.

An other, similar way to solve it would be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Detailed", // Route name
    "order/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Orders", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Make sure that the static part in the route, **order**, does not match the name of your actual orders controller, otherwise you'll have the same problem, rendering *[url]/orders* unreachable with an *System.ArgumentException* instead of calling the Index() method (the default route)

The negative side of this approach is that you'll need to do this for every controller where you would like to have such functionality.

Comment: to prevent the home/search error. You can use Regex to enforce that id can only be numeric. routes.MapRoute("", "{controller}/{id}", new { controller = "Orders", action = "Detail" }, new { id = @"\d+" });

Comment: Came to mind later aw well, that you can specify constraints. So you could define a constraint for the id and for the controller as well, so it would only use the Orders controller

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this route before the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute("SomeName", "{controller}/{id}", new { controller = "Orders", action = "Details" });
```

Notice how the {action} has been removed from the URL parameter.